# Reading data from text file with variable numbers of Column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, text

I am reading data from a text file in python using pandas. There are no header values (column names) assigned to the data in the text file. I want to reshape the data into a readable form. The problem i am facing is variable column lengths
For example in my text file i have

```
    1,2,3,4,5,Hello,7,8
    1,2,3,4,5,7,8,
    1,2,3,4,5,7,8,
    1,2,3,4,5,Hello,7,8,
```

Now when i create a data frame I want to make sure that in the second row instead of Hello a "NAN" is written as the value for that column is not present. and in the end after giving column names and rearranging the data frame will look like.

```
    1,2,3,4,5,Hello,7,8
    1,2,3,4,5,"NA,"7,8,
    1,2,3,4,5,"NA",7,8,
    1,2,3,4,5,Hello,7,8,
```

Comment: are missing values present only in second column?

Comment: Which column should `C` in the 2nd row be written to?

Comment: how are these missing values represented in your text file? is there a whitespace, a tab... or how would you know which column the value originally belongs to, if it is written like your example?

Comment: @meW YES only in second

Comment: @MayankPorwal in this case third column

Comment: @Flob they are represented by (,) let me edit the question and post the data as well

Comment: @Flob done ! check now let me know if you are still don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to updated question and also a generalized solution for such case.

```
focus_col_idx = 5   # The column where you want to bring NaN in expected output
last_idx = df.shape[1] - 1

# Fetching the index of rows which have None in last column 
idx = df[df[last_idx].isnull()].index

# Shifting the column values for those rows with index idx
df.iloc[idx,focus_col_idx+1:] = df.iloc[idx,focus_col_idx:last_idx].values

# Putting NaN for second column where row index is idx
df.iloc[idx,focus_col_idx] = np.NaN

df


+---+----+---+---+---+---+-------+---+-----+
|   |  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |   5   | 6 |  7  |
+---+----+---+---+---+---+-------+---+-----+
| 0 |  1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | Hello | 7 | 8.0 |
| 1 |  1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | NaN   | 7 | 8.0 |
| 2 |  1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | NaN   | 7 | 8.0 |
| 3 |  1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | Hello | 7 | 8.0 |
+---+----+---+---+---+---+-------+---+-----+
```

**Answer to previous data**

Assuming only one column is having missing value (say 2nd column as per your previous data). Here's a quick sol -

```
df = pd.read_table('SO.txt',sep='\,', header=None)
df

+---+---+---+---+---+------+
|   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  4   |
+---+---+---+---+---+------+
| 0 | A | B | C | D | E    |
| 1 | A | C | D | E | None |
+---+---+---+---+---+------+


# Fetching the index of rows which have None in last column 
idx = df[df[4].isnull()].index
idx
# Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')

# Shifting the column values for those rows with index idx
df.iloc[idx,2:] = df.iloc[idx,1:4].values
df

+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | A | B | C | D | E |
| 1 | A | C | C | D | E |        # <- Notice the shifting.
+---+---+---+---+---+---+


# Putting NaN for second column where row index is idx
df.iloc[idx,1] = np.NaN

# Final output
df
+---+---+-----+---+---+---+
|   | 0 |  1  | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+-----+---+---+---+
| 0 | A | B   | C | D | E |
| 1 | A | NaN | C | D | E |
+---+---+-----+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Let me provide comments.

Comment: check now. If anything unclear let me know. Or if you want answer for updated question!

Comment: sure. I'll give you a generalized solution by that time.

Comment: its giving me an error "Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185550/discussion-between-mew-and-jeff).